Created a new FormBuilder form but Civi sends me over 200 emails
I have created a new form using CiviCRM Formbuilder, however when something is submitted, the system sends me multiple emails to a point the site stops working due to overloading resources.
I will get the normal case open email, but then will get "copy of, copy of, copy of" etc. emails until I delete the case and activity from the MYSQL database.
The form is setup to create a new case for whichever user submits it and send an email to example email address, this allows us to keep knowlege of when a case is created.
It works if I create the case manually, so it is an issue with the form, but I can't see any issues in the setup of said form. I have included the settings I have for the form to show no emails are set to be sent.


Dan - I've edited your question to talk about 'form' instead of 'webform' to avoid confusion.  'Webform' is a specific Drupal module.  FormBuilder forms are not webforms.

Do you have any CiviRules set up?

Sounds like a loop...!

I do have civirules setup to notify me of a new activity via email, but im not sure how i would stop this repeating?

Might it be that when the case is created an activity is created, which triggers an email based on your CiviRule, and the creation of the email might create an activity which then triggers another email, and so on?

I have since found out that I had a rule to email me when a new activity is created, and this email then created a new activity etc.
Disabling this rule fixed the issue, but now I need to create a rule to send a notification when a new email is sent into a case.
